# Issue with delete else update

Tags: teradata

I have one scenario as below

```
Generted_I'd    Correct_gen_I'd
223455.              13456
256782.              14678
```

Want to check for the correct_gen_I'd in a table A, if it exists in Table B then delete the corresponding generated_I'd i.e 223455.
If it doesn't exists in table A, then update the corresponding generated_I'd with the correct_id in table A i.e update 223455 to 13456.

Can anyone please provide the approach/query to achieve this

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth for the edit! Can you please help me with the logic for this.

Comment: @dnoeth will merge statement do this?

Comment: I don't get what you want, MERGE can do DELETE/UPDATE plus INSERT on (not) matched

Comment: if 13456 is present in a table say A, then delete 223455 from that table A, else if 13456 is not present there then update 223455 to 13456 in the same table A. I fa table b with correct_id and wrongly generated id. Let me know if  i am clear here.

Comment: As you have two different WHERE-conditions you need two statements (using EXISTS/NOT EXISTS?)